# A* Search in unweighted graph

Tags: search, graph, distance

This is mainly a theoretical question and it's quite simple,so I thought I can answer for the questions correctly, but my answers were wrong and I want to know why. I have a graph which looks like this.

[image]

Where: `K` is the start point, `V` is the end point, `X` are the points where you can't move, the `-` `|` are the edges. The cost between every edge is `1`, and the distance heuristic is euclidean distance in plane.
The first iteration begins with the `K` and `I` had to answer to the following questions:

1. In which iteration we will reach the `V` (end point)? The answers were: 9, 6, 8 or 7; I answered 6 but it was incorrect
2. At the third iteration which vertex will get in the list of closed edges? Answers: `I`, `G`, `H`, `F`. My answer `H` (incorrect)
3. After how many iterations we will reach the terminal state. My Answer 6, but incorrect again.

So somebody please can explain the correct steps of solving the problem and the answers for these questions? Thank you.

Comment: Could you list the steps you went through

Comment: Sure. So because every edge cost is 1 I calculated the vertex distances with euclidean heuristic (the cost to reach the vertex+the cost to reach the final vertex from that specific one). The A distance 11, B 11, C distance 7 G 5, H 5,J 5, M 5 L 5. The first iteration begins with K, so I thought the next will be H or G but because of the heuristic H has a closer distance, so I choose H, after that J, M,L and V. That's 6 iteration.

Comment: I tried to work it out, but no matter how I do it, I cannot finish the algorithm in 9 steps or fewer. It could be done in 11 steps, but it's actually ambiguous and it could take 12 steps as well. V can be put into the open list in the 10th iteration, but that doesn't count because the algorithm is only done when V comes out of the open list (while V is open, it is still possible to find "shortcuts" to it)

Comment: That's interesting. What steps did you do? Maybe it's about the closed list? I think my professor lives in another dimension.